# OSGI - handling 3rd party JARs and their dependencies

Tags: java, osgi

I'm new in OSGI development and am struggling to understand how best to handle dependent JARs.

i.e. if I'm creating a bundle the likelihood is that I will need to use a few 3rd party JARs. When I create my bundle JAR to deploy to OSGI, obviously these 3rd party JARs are not included and thus the bundle will not run.

I understand that one option is to turn these JARs into bundles and deploy them to the OSGI container. When I bundled and try deploy third party jar it throws error for their own dependent jars and these dependencies are endless and not possible to fulfill.

What is the best solution to this?

-- Anurag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolve third party jar issue actually I forger to add following tag in my POM.xml file 
<_exportcontents>*

My issue is resolve, thanks to all of you for your support and giving me valuable clues.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner with osgi then I would not recommend to bundle bigger libs yourself. Often more than defining some import and export headers is required and it can become very difficult. Fortunately a lot of libs are available as bundles.

If the original lobs is not yet a bundle then you can search in maven central for a bundled version from servicemix bundles.

Using apache karaf is also often a big help. There are karaf features with predefined deps for a lot of libs like activemq, cxf, camel, openjpa, ...

In the worst case you can embed the lib and all deps in your own jar. This tends to cause class loading issues though if you try to share some classes between bundles.

What lib is the problem in your case?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of libraries you mention (log4j, quartz, dom4j) have already been converted to OSGi bundles by Springsource. You can find them in the [Springsource Enterprise Bundle Repository](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app). All Hibernate libraries > 4.2 are also osgified.

Answer (score 0):

You have three choices:

1. Find the library in some pre-made bundles ([Springsource Repository](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/), [Eclipse Orbit Repository](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/), etc.)
2. Include the libraries into your bundle as an external library (Make a directory lib, copy your jar files there, and reference them from the `Bundle-Classpath` element in `MANIFEST.MF`)
3. Convert the library into an OSGi bundle (e.g. with the `bnd wrap`converter, example [here](http://fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.2/deploy_osgi/DeployJar-Convert.html))